# Failing to POST, any troubleshooting tips?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, hardware-failure

**My problem:**

I took a break to have lunch and when I came back, my computer would not POST or display.  I haven't changed anything recently.  It's about 6 years old.  The CPU led on the motherboard lights up.  Most fans are spinning, except for the GPU fans, which spin very briefly; some years ago, one of the GPU fans stopped spinning unless the temps get very high, at which point it starts spinning.  The motherboard speaker I bought doesn't make any beeps.

Specs:

CPU: AMD FX8350, GPU: Radeon 7950, Motherboard: m5a99fx pro r2.0, PSU: Rosewill Capstone 750 RAM: GSkill Ripjaws 2x4GB 1600 DDR3 (also monitor, mouse, keyboard)

**What I've tried:**

I've breadboarded the computer, using only the items in the above specs.

I bought a multimeter and tested the voltages from the PSU.  From the 24 pin motherboard connection, to the CPU and GPU connections, everything is within spec.

I've tried booting using combinations of 1 or both RAM sticks, and different slots.

I've tried replacing the CMOS battery and clearing the CMOS by moving that little 2 pin connector over.

I've tried reseating everything, including the CPU, which did not have any bent pins.

**What I'm planning:**

The PSU seems fine based off the voltages I read.  Unless both RAM sticks failed, I think the RAM is fine, too.  I hear CPUs rarely ever fail, so I doubt it's that.  The monitor turns on and I can switch inputs, brightness, etc., so I doubt it's that either.

Based on how the GPU fans aren't spinning right, I think it's that.  However, it could also be the motherboard.  The only way I can think to narrow it down further, besides buying a GPU or motherboard, is find a GPU I can borrow.

Does anyone know of any troubleshooting methods I missed?